Prompt page in Power BI - Load the embedded paginated report only after I select slicer values
I created a paginated report (including parameters) and embedded it in the standard report, then added the slicers and set them up to use the parameter values.
Parameters are: country, date valid
The problem is that as soon as I open the report, the embedded paginated report starts loading all rows automatically. I'd like to be able to select the parameter values first in my slicers (and these can be on a separate prompt page or on the same page as the embedded paginated report), then the paginated report can load with these values applied.
How to best approach this? According to my knowledge, a prompt page functionality (as known from Cognos for example) is not implemented in Power BI.
I could also take any advice regarding the standard table visual - how to prevent loading all data at once, if I want to start loading the data in the table visual only after selecting the slicer values first?
Any ideas or pointers will be much appreciated, thank you

any luck with this? This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve as well. Especially being a long time Cognos pro, not able to create text prompts in power bi is bit annoying. Please let me know if you found a way for this issue.

This not an answer to the posted question. Please use the comment feature instead.

Hello, yes i have been able to do it. My use case was one big table visual with three prompts needed.
I created three slicers and used a functionality "Apply all slicers". This way, i can choose values in all three slicers first and only then hit Apply, the table in the table visual then gets filtered by the selected values in all those three slicers.

By default, the table started loading data right away - i only had one page containing the table and those three slicers. To prevent the table from happening, i had the slicers on Page 1 and the table visual on table 2. Additional functionality used in this case was "sync all slicers".
I can elaborate further if you need.
